# Read WMF image from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, .net-3.5, image-conversion

I am using a SqlDataReader and I am trying to read from a table I converted from an Access file, and is in SQL Server 2008.

The datatype is now a varbinary(max).

How do I convert this, so I can have it as System.Drawing.Image?

It is a Windows MetaFile and I want to convert it to a PNG or GIF and save it to the filesystem.

It appears this won't be correct as I get an error that it can't convert to Image.

```
System.Drawing.Image LocationImage = sdr.GetSqlBinary(2)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SqlBytes](http://System.Drawing.Image). Use [Image.FromStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlbytes.stream.aspx) to load the image from the [SqlBytes.Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlbytes.stream.aspx). Use [CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlbytes.stream.aspx) on the reader to load large size images:

```
using (SqlDataReader sdr=cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
{
...
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBytes imageBytes = srd.GetSqBytes(2);
System.Drawing.Image locationImage = Image.FromStream(imageBytes.Stream);
}
```

To save it as PNG/GIF:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update table set image=@image where ...")

MemoryStream streamOutput = new MemoryStream();
image.Save(streamOutput, ImageFormat.Png);
SqlBytes imageBytes = new SqlBytes(streamOutput); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", imageBytes);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

**Update**

I'm not sure Image.FromStream can load WMF format. It can load EMF afaik, but I'm not sure about WMF. Perhaps routing the call through a [Metafile(Stream)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h5aa6y9.aspx) constructor will work, I'm not a graphics expert by any stretch.

Comment: thank you. I am down to Image.FromStream, and you are correct that that didn't work, but using Metafile(Stream) doesn't as this constructor wants a byte array.  So, I am working on that.